# How OpenCart controller handles route=catalog/product/edit. Which view file?

Tags: model-view-controller, controller, opencart

I want to know which view file OpenCart controller uses when it redirects to `route=catalog/product/edit`, in the admin area.
I want to change the HTML code of that HTML file. If it is `product_form.tpl` it is not showing any changes when I edit it.

Comment: It's product_form.tpl, what are you trying to do? which version of opencart?

Comment: I want to change some HTML but if i do so it does not change in the output. i.e., if i add <script>alert("hello world"); </script> it does not show alert box. version of opencart is 2.2